# Suppose $\psi:Z_n \to Z_n$ is a ring homorphism. Show that $\psi(s) =bs$ for some $b \in Z_n$ where $b^2=b$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra

$\psi (s) =bs$ should be true for all $s \in Z_n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** 
$$\phi(s)=\phi(1+1+...+1)=\phi(1)+...+\phi(1)$$
Where there are $s$ terms in the sum.

**Hint 2:**
$$\phi(1)=\phi(1 \cdot 1)$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\psi(1)=\psi(1^2)=\psi(1)^2$.